# Why are certain competitions called a "Classic?"

Tags: meaning, etymology, history

In the town I live in, there have been a number of competitive events called "classics" (e.g. "Bicycle Classic," "Golf Classic").

I assume this term is used because the event is a long-standing, annual tradition. Is that correct? Are there any guidelines as to what should and shouldn't be called a classic?

Comment: There is exactly one guideline for names: it's a name, so you can call it whatever you want. A Microsoft needs to be neither micro nor soft, a Federal Reserve does not need to be federal or a reserve, and a Bicycle Classic could be a pie-eating contest for all we know.

Comment: True that, @RegDwigнt, but this is not a question about a single name. There are a myriad of events that share "Classic" in their title, I, for one, would be very interested to see where this leads.

Answer (score 6):

> A classic is an outstanding example of a particular style, something of lasting worth or with a timeless quality. … *Classic* is used to describe many major, long-standing sporting events.

(src: WP, see link below).

See also:

- The section on [Sport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic#Sport) in the Wikipedia article 'Classic:'

> Many sporting events take the name classic …

- AHD cited in [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/classic)

> 6. A traditional event, especially a major sporting event that is held annually: *a golf classic*.

Answer (score 1):

> The noun classic means something that's very high quality,
>   particularly if it has lasting value. ([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/classic))

- The pristine Model T Ford that you keep in your garage is a *classic*

> Classical is the customary word when reference is made to the arts and
>   literature of ancient Greece and Rome (a classical scholar, classical
>   Latin, classical metres).

- The works studied, and also the subject itself and the study ofthe
  subject, are called (the) Classics. (Fowler's Modern English usage)

> Classical is also applied to serious or conventional music (i.e. that
>   of Beethoven, Mozart, etc.) as distinct from light or popular music;
>   and in physics to the concepts which preceded relativity and quantum
>   theory. (Fowler's....)
>
> classic (adj.)  1610s, "of the highest class; approved as a model,"
>   Originally in English, "of the first class;"
>   meaning "belonging to standard authors of Greek and Roman antiquity"
>   is attested from 1620s. ([etymology.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=classic))

- Classic means 'of acknowledged excellence'
  (the classic textbook on the subject),
  or 'remarkably typical' (a classic case of
  cerebral palsy)